# Do I need to fill all columns in an SQL Database to pass a variable

Tags: html, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to pass variables to a sql database.

The database is set up as follows:

```
id, comment1, comment2, comment3, comment4
```

I am executing this by this code:

```
$comment1 = $_POST['comment1'];
$sql = "UPDATE comments SET comment1='$comment1' ";
mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
header("Location:index.php");
exit();
```

Is it possible to just add one variable at a time i.e. just comment 1? Or will I need to add all the variables to the database. The code is not working right now when I try to pass one variable.

Comment: I'm guessing it is because they are configured to not contain any null, and it is the default when creating columns

Comment: what means *is not working*. An error or wrong data?

Comment: It's because your other columned doesn't accept empty or null values you need to enable accept null to other columnes.

Answer (score 1):

Need to ensure it is set as null allowed and it will work